# Basic HTTP request in VueJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, frontend, vue-component

I'm totally new to Vue and I'm learning a bit "on the go" while coding so sorry if my question is stupid. I'm just trying to make a request and display the result.

With the bellow code, `{{info}}` doesn't display anything, I also don't get any errors... What am I missing?

idk.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

new Vue({
  el: '#idk',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
```

Page2.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="idk">
  {{ info }} hmm
  </div>

</template>
```

App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// Vuesax Component Framework
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css' //Material Icons
import 'vuesax/dist/vuesax.css' // Vuesax
Vue.use(Vuesax)

import './idk.js'
// Styles: SCSS
import './assets/scss/main.scss'
// Tailwind
import '@/assets/css/main.css'
// Vue Router
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Why did you create two vue instances?

Comment: Try `this.info = response.data`. See https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema

Comment: That didn't work. Problem doesn't seem to come from the request, if I hardcore a value it's also empty. And seems I missunderstood aboue vue instance and should only have 1 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `idk.js` logic into your `Page2` component. The issue is that when you include `idk.js`, the element with ID `idk` won't exist.

For example, assuming that `Page2` is included by `App` or something like that...

```html
<!-- Page2.vue -->
<template>
  <div id="idk">
  {{ info }} hmm
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data: () => ({ info: null }),
  created () { //  created runs earlier so will get your data quicker
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data //  note "response.data" here
      })
  }
})
</script>
```

You can then remove `idk.js`.

Comment: Thank you, seems I missunderstood vue a bit... So it seems I should never create another vue instance and instead use export default. + get rid of bad habit of splitting js, css & templates